# What does 解压密码233（19个3）mean?

Tags: translation

I couldn't get the whole signification out of Google Traduction.
I know it begins like "Password for extraction :" but I am not able to translate 个 so I can't find what the actual password is.

Comment: 23333333333333333333

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Password to decompress is 233(19 "three")

Answer (score 2):

解压密码 is the password for a zipped file when you need to extract the files.
23333333333 is not a typical chinese word, you can use it as a slang which means LOL. You dont say 23333333333 in your real life just like you dont say LOL in a conversion. It's only intended to express "that's funny" in your social network.
Putting them together, 解压密码233（19个3), it doesnt look like a sentence to me.

Comment: it is called 名词谓语句 sentence with a nominal predicate， other examples: 她医生，明天十月四号，今天晴天，这快肥皂六毛六，他二十一（岁），他哪里人？现在无点半

Comment: but we DO say 23333333333 in the real life

Comment: @xmcp When you found something funny, you say LOL?

Answer (score 0):

I am Chinese I have same questions about these in English.

19 个 3 means " the number of 3 is 19 ", so the password is 233333333333333333333.

『个』in Chinese means "the number of".

In Chinese, there must have a "quantifier" between number and noun.

> eg.
>       In English you can say : one person and in Chinese you should 一个人( one 个 person )
>
> ```
> one finger 一个手指（one 个 finger）
>
> two oranges 两个橘子( two 个 orange)
> ```

And in Chinese, we don't have "plural", one apple is "一个苹果"， two apples "两个苹果", "苹果" will always be "苹果", not "苹果s", no matter how many apples there are.

Another thing about "quantifier" in Chinese is that different noun has different "quantifier" for it.

> eg.
>       a pig. you should say 一只猪 or 一头猪
>
> ```
> a mobile phone. you should say 一部手机
>
> a car. you should say 一辆车
> ```

If you don't know which quantifier should, you can use 个.